# Local builds using Nativescript Sidekick (macOS)

Tags: nativescript, angular-nativescript

I am trying to make local build using NS Sidekick to get advantage of my MacBook Pro and seems like there are some issue with the certificate/provisioning profile.

According to the doc, I have edited the file build.xcconfig like this:

```
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage;
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1,2;
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 9.0;
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = 6W9G86W4T4
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Distribution: MyCompanyName (6W9G86W4T4)
PROVISIONING_PROFILE = 39cd1593-32fc-420a-a0fe-03f12d7e631f
```

I have imported to my keychain the iPhone Distribution: `MyCompanyName (6W9G86W4T4)` certificate, also downloaded the .mobileprovision file to somewhere in the Mac corresponding to the `39cd1593-32fc-420a-a0fe-03f12d7e631f` (uuid of the provisioning profile). When I build for local/release on my Sidekick, it fails with this error:

```
[19-04-04 16:37:07.447] Build failed. Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 70 Error output: 
 2019-04-04 16:37:06.017 xcodebuild[68104:596846] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/0v/034z5q516y3gg8_z75hbm6sm0000gn/T/MyApp_2019-04-04_16-37-06.017.xcdistributionlogs'.
error: exportArchive: "MyApp.app" requires a provisioning profile.
Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""MyApp.app" requires a provisioning profile." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="MyApp.app" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}
OUTPUT 1
```

Any tips for this?

Thanks!

Comment: yours one is iPhone Distribution profile, try with development profile.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the comment, I would like to point out that I want to build for release, publish to the app stores. Using a Development profile doesn't make sense for me, does it?